# Create namespace class alias for a non-namespace class

Tags: php, class, alias, extend

I'm new to PHP 5.6+ trying to catch up, I want to create a compatibility layer for an application, consider the following scenario

```php
// classA.php, a non spaced class
class A {
  // ONLY fallback const + methods / work as just an alias for B (below)
}

// classAchild.php, a child non spaced class
class Achild extends A {
  // ONLY fallback const + methods / work as just an alias for Bclass (below)
}

// B.php, a spaced class
namespace Abstract\Context;
class B {
  // ALL const + methods
}

// Bchild.php, a child non spaced class
namespace Abstract\Context\B\Subcontext;
class Bchild extends B {
  // ALL const + methods
}
```

The class `A` is a PHP 4+ version of the class B which is PHP 7+, functionally these classes and their child classes are equivalent, however in different contexts.

Let me explain:

- I am now in the situation where I have to create a namespaced alias for `Bchild` based on an existing `Achild`.
- When working in the context where all classes namespace (latest application version), `B` is always used, but when working in the older application, `Bchild` is always there to fill the content for `Achild` or sometimes patch it.

Something like this:

```php
if ( !class_exists('Abstract\Context\B\Subcontext\Bchild') ){
  if ( !class_exists('Abstract\Context\B') ){
    class 'Abstract\Context\B' extends A{} // define an alias for B with existing A
  }
  class 'Abstract\Context\B\Subcontext\Bchild' extends Achild{} // define an alias for Bclass with existing Achild
}
```

If you know how to do this, please let me know.

Comment: This question is too abstract with too little context for me. I for one don't really understand what you're asking.

Comment: I updated sample code, please check and ask me anything, I can explain everything I have in mind (except knowledge on this matter).

Comment: Yeah, no, that didn't really help. Why do you (think you) need to do it like this in the first place? In what situation would a class not be defined and require you to define it dynamically?

Comment: It's a matter of folder structure and file naming difference between the two applications. Basically I don't want to repeat the entire class content with the same thing just to use a different class name (and add additional namespace) where possible. Also when `A` "family" is deprecated and dusted, I can just remove the compatibility layer and it's all good.

Comment: Soo… `namespace Abstract\Context { if (!class_exists(...)) { class B extends \A {} } }`…?

Comment: Something like that. It's really hard to explain. Man I should probably storm php.net someday, clean up some javascript in the brain cache. Let me try that real quick.

Comment: @deceze if you feel like closing/deleting this question, go ahead, I understand from your last comment something I didn't from other topics. I would rather post an answer explaining things and elaborating some ideas to improve the code, I will mark it in a heart beat. My problem is now solved.